# Differential Equations: When do constants combine to be another constant?

Tags: absolute-value

I'm trying to isolate $y$. I have a constant times a negative one? Do I ignore the negative and leave is as a constant? Here's what I'm working with...

$$|(6-2(y^3))| = ke^{-3\times2}$$

For a positive portion: $6-2(y^3) = ke^{-3\times-2}$

For negative portion: $6-2(y^3) = -ke^{-3\times-2}$

Does the negative portion just simplify to $ke^{-3\times-2}$ ?
I don't understand the rules of constants...

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the sign of $k$. In the positive case, you have $K>0$ since exponential is always positive, in the other you have $-k <0$ which is again $k>0$. You can simplify this to just $k e^{-3x-2}$ as you said, but then you have $k<0$.

Comment: ok. I think I understand. So let's say I simplify to -2(y^3) = ke^(-3x^2)-6. Would that mean y^3 = ke^(-3x^2)+3 ?

Comment: yes, but still you have 2 cases, if $y^3 <3$ then $k>0$ and if $y^3\geq 3$ then $k\leq 0$